# how to find instructions per cycle in a processor?

Tags: computer-science, cpu-architecture

So i'm doing a problem and it asks to find the IPC for several processors. I understand the formula, however it gives me: "20.00E+09" as the number of instructions, could somebody please explain to me what this means? is it: 20,000,000,000?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is.  The E+09 is a fill-in for 20.00 x 10^9

Answer (score 0):

I have just been doing some benchmarking on an 11th gen Intel I5 Core at 2.60 Ghz.

Looking at the assemby code I calculated that the program was running at circa 33 billion instructions per second. There are 2.6 billion cycles per second and this implies 12.6 instructions per cycle.

The program has to be carefully optimized in order to achieve this so that the program branches constrain the instruction pipeline hardly at all and complex calculations must be in progress between the reads and writes from memory.

Comment: It's unusual for a CPU with a base frequency of 2.6GHz to actually run that slow most of the time.  That "sticker" frequency is the worst-case non-turbo frequency, which it might slow down to with all cores busy running energy-intensive instructions like SIMD FP math.  (Like prime95 which does close to 2x 256-bit FMAs per clock cycle).  Use `perf stat ./my_program` on Linux to count  instructions and core clock cycles.  (RDTSC counts reference cycles, which may tick somewhat close to the sticker frequency, but don't change with core frequency.)

Comment: A CPU like [i5-11400](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/212270/intel-core-i511400-processor-12m-cache-up-to-4-40-ghz.html) is rated 2.6GHz, max turbo 4.4. It's Rocket Lake (https://en.wikichip.org/wiki/intel/microarchitectures/rocket_lake); the cores are a backport of Ice Lake to 14nm, so the pipeline is 5 uops wide.  If you have a lot of not-taken branches, that means a theoretical max throughput of 7 IPC on one core, with two macro-fused cmp/jcc branches per clock, at most one of them not-taken.  Without branch macro-fusion, max IPC is 5 instructions per core clock cycle.

Comment: It's literally impossible that an 11th-gen Intel CPU managed 12.6 IPC.  Like I said, perhaps you're running at max turbo but counting cycles of a different clock, like the TSC.  And perhaps you're counting instructions across multiple threads?  Because even 12.6 / (4.4/2.6) is an impossibly high 7.4.  Normal definitions of IPC count each core separately, e.g. one cycle on each of two CPU cores is two CPU cycles.  To get IPC, you count total instructions across all threads, and total CPU cycles across the cores while those threads were running on them.  (HW performance counters can do that.)

Comment: Note that different cores can be running at different clock speeds (at least in theory, and maybe in practice for turbo frequencies on Intel).  And/or one can pause its clock temporarily.  So for that reason as well as by convention, IPC is defined as a per-thread / per-core measurement, how efficient each core is.  Having more cores doesn't boost IPC.  I guess you could say it gives you more CPU-cycles per second, but usually we just look at multiple cores as a separate multiplier for throughput things like peak FLOPs chip-wide.

Comment: (Correction to earlier comment, 2 macro-fused branches per clock, at most one of the **taken**.  Taken branches are more expensive for the pipeline including front-end, and only one execution unit can run both predicted-taken and predicted-not-taken branch uops.  There's another execution unit that can run only predicted-not-taken uops.  It's been that way since Haswell: https://www.realworldtech.com/haswell-cpu/4/)

Comment: Thanks indeed for your comments.
I was surprised at how high the figure I obtained was.
I checked and 25.5% of the CPU was being used.
(There is only one thread anyway.)
If I find time I will look at the execution paths.
The not taken paths are really short : (in one case just a bit or by 1.)

Comment: If you have a quad-core CPU, then that's 100% of one core, as you'd expect for a single-threaded program.